# Listening to shiurim in bed

Tags: torah-study, sleep

Can one fall asleep listening to shiurim about stories, not gemara or Chumash, but really just stories?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Ben and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I never heard that it’s halachitly bad to fall asleep to shiurim on Torah, in fact, it might be better, since your subconscious mind will absorb it.